# How to define enum mapping in OpenAPI?

Tags: enums, swagger, openapi

I am designing an API and I want to define an enum *Severity* which can have values LOW, MEDIUM or HIGH. Internally *Severity* gets stored as an integer so I want to map these to 2,1 and 0 respectively. Is there a way to do this in an OpenAPI definition? This is currently what I have for *Severity*:

```yaml
 severity:
   type: string
   enum:
   - HIGH
   - MEDIUM
   - LOW
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

#### OpenAPI 3.1

OpenAPI 3.1 uses the latest JSON Schema, and the [recommended way](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/348#issuecomment-336194030) to annotate individual enum values in JSON Schema is to use `oneOf`+`const` instead of `enum`. This way you can specify both custom names (`title`) and descriptions for enum values.

```yaml
Severity:
  type: integer
  oneOf:
  - title: HIGH
    const: 2
    description: An urgent problem
  - title: MEDIUM
    const: 1
  - title: LOW
    const: 0
    description: Can wait forever
```

#### OpenAPI 3.0 and 2.0

These versions do not have a way to define custom names for enum values, but some tools provide `x-` extensions for this purpose. For example:

- [AutoRest](https://github.com/Azure/autorest) supports [`x-ms-enum`](https://github.com/Azure/autorest/tree/master/docs/extensions#x-ms-enum).
- [NSwag](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag) supports [`x-enumNames`](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/wiki/Enums#enum-names-and-descriptions):

  ```yaml
  Severity:
    type: integer
    enum: [2, 1, 0]
    x-enumNames: [HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW]
  ```
- [openapi-typescript-codegen](https://github.com/ferdikoomen/openapi-typescript-codegen) supports [`x-enum-varnames`](https://github.com/ferdikoomen/openapi-typescript-codegen/blob/master/docs/custom-enums.md):

  ```yaml
  Severity:
    type: integer
    enum: [2, 1, 0]
    x-enum-varnames: [HIGH, MEDIUM, LOW]
  ```

Check with your tooling vendors to see if they have a similar extension.

Comment: Any mapping Technical "Keyword" => Display "Label" available for code generation ?

Comment: @FrançoisF. I don't know. But the most popular codegens are open source, so you can customize them to your needs.

Answer (score 7):

**Open API 3.0**

You can use description:

```yaml
Severity:
  type: integer
  enum: [2, 1, 0]
  description: >
    dictionary:
      * 2 HIGH
      * 1 MEDIUM
      * 0 LOW
```

It will not affect automatic code generation, but will be visible in generated documentation.

Comment: here what would be the type of request object for this contract?
Here type is int then it expects int type or enum type as input?