# How to define an enum with different name and value in OAS 3.1.0 to be generated in the build?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums, openapi

In Java, it is quite easy to create an Enum like

```
public enum EnumType {
    TYPE_A ("Some text for type A"),
    TYPE_B ("Some text for type B"),
    TYPE_C ("Some text for type C")
}
```

I want to be able to create a similar structure with the OpenAPI specification.

This would be easy enough if the names and values are the same with :

```
openapi: 3.1.0
(...)
components:
  schemas:
    EnumType:
      enum: [ TYPE_A,
              TYPE_B,
              TYPE_C
      ]
```

But how can I do it with OpenAPI? IntelliJ will not allow the `const` property in the snippet below, saying it is prohibited.

```
openapi: 3.1.0
(...)
components:
  schemas:
    EnumType:
      oneOf:
        - title: TYPE_A
          const: 'Some text for type A'
        - title: TYPE_B
          const: 'Some text for type B'
        - title: TYPE_C
          const: 'Some text for type C'
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Your spec is OpenAPI 3.1 - does IntelliJ (or whatever OpenAPI editor plugin you use in IntelliJ) actually support 3.1? It might be complaining because it does not recognize the `const` keyword which is new in 3.1.

Comment: Likely not. Apparently, there is no IntelliJ support so far for OAS 3.1.0 - be it native or via plugins. As long as the code gets generated, I don't mind designing the API in a third party tool. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: So far there's almost no [tooling support](https://openapi.tools/) for OAS 3.1. You may want to stick with 3.0 and use `enum` with `x-` extensions ([like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66471626/113116)) and customize the code generator to  understand those extensions (assuming your codegen supports such customizations).

Comment: The schema is correct. The problem is with the tooling.