# OpenApi 3.0 Enum values structure

Tags: swagger, openapi

I am using OpenApi 3.0 and I have encountered a requirement with enum with some extra fields.
Example:

```yaml
enum:
  - name: a
    x-field-uid: 1
    description: some description
  - name: b
    x-field-uid: 2
    description: some description
  - name: c
    x-field-uid: 3
    description: some description
```

Though I did not find anything similar pattern from the openapi spec, but I tried using the above format for enums and openapi spec validation doesn't through any error.

I wonder if this can be used or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question -- [How to define enum mapping in OpenAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66465888/113116)

Comment: @Helen Thanks the answer provided is similar to what I have asked for