Extensible Enum classes not getting generated using openapi-generator-maven-plugin
I am using OpenAPI spec with version 3.0.1 and trying to generate the client code using the openapi-generator-maven-plugin version 7.1.0.
TransactionType:
  type: string
  x-extensible-enum:
    - "AUTHORIZE"
    - "CAPTURE"
    - "REFUND"
    - "VOID"

But instead of generating an enum class, it gives back a string.
Could someone please help?

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/66465888/296328

OpenAPI Generator does not support x-extensible-enum, that's why it generates that field as just a string. Here's a somewhat related feature request: [REQ] Extensible enums - how to model and generate.
You can try customizing the built-in templates to process the x-extensible-enum extension according to your needs, e.g. generate the desired enum class.

According to the documentation, the only enum-related extensions supported by OpenAPI Generator out-of-the-box are x-enum-varnames and x-enum-descriptions.
